# How to add property to external namespaced interface provided by lib

Tags: typescript

I'm having trouble adding a property to an interface provided by the `@feathersjs/feathers` lib.

This is their interface (I'll summarize and show the relevant parts)

```
// @feathersjs/feathers/index.d.ts

declare const createApplication: Feathers;
export = createApplication;

interface Feathers {
    <T = any>(): createApplication.Application<T>;
    readonly ACTIVATE_HOOKS: unique symbol;
    version: string;
    default: Feathers;
}

declare namespace createApplication {
    //.... A BUNCH OF INTERFACES
    interface HookContext<T = any> {
        readonly app: Application;    // <-- what I want to extend
        //.... A BUNCH OF PROPERTIES
    }
    //.... A BUNCH OF INTERFACES
    interface Application<ServiceTypes = {}> extends EventEmitter {
        //.... A BUNCH OF PROPERTIES
        // <---- I WANT TO ADD A PROPERTY `logger?: any`
    }
}
```

How do I accomplish this? (adding `logger?: any` as specified in the code block above)

I've looked into declaration merging as a method because it looks like a really clean solution that preserves separation of concern, but I can't seem to get it working.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to monkey-patch a typedef (and somewhere else assign the logger there) you probably want to add a `.d.ts` file that patches the library. I haven't used `feathers`, but I generated a new app and if you wish to achieve eg. this

```
const app: Application = express(feathers());
...
app.logger('Logging is good');
```

then add a type patch file with `.d.ts` extension to your build path and define something like this:

```
import feathers from '@feathersjs/feathers';

declare module '@feathersjs/feathers' {
  export interface Application {
    logger(msg: string): void;
  }
}
```

You do of course need to really assign the logger to the application for the logger to actually work. With the monkey patch above, this works in the project generated with Feathers CLI:

```
const app: Application = express(feathers());
app.logger = console.log;
app.logger('Logging is good');
```

and if you rename `logger` to anything else in the type patch the code above will produce an error.

Comment: sorry it took me forever to finish what I was doing so I could get back to TS porting. Worked like a dream, thanks a tonne!